# Properly wait for a global variable to initialize

Tags: go

I have a global variable that reads a config file which I use across different functions. When I execute the main method, and try to read a value from the configuration, the value is not ready yet, so I get a weird value `:ᾐ` which is supposed to be 8080. What is the proper way for waiting for the global var to be ready.

```
var conf = getGeneralConfig()

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    fmt.Println(":" + string(conf.PORT))
    router.HandleFunc("/add", add).Methods("POST")
   // conf is not yet ready here
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+string(conf.PORT), router))
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For initializing a variable before main function use `init()` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable is initialized before `main()` is run. See the [package initialization section](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization) of the language specification for all of the details.

The issue is with the string conversion `string(conf.PORT)`. The [specification says this about the conversion used in the application](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type):

> Converting a signed or unsigned integer value to a string type yields a string containing the UTF-8 representation of the integer.

The string "ᾐ" is the UTF-8 encoding of the rune 8080. The fix is to use [strconv.Itoa](https://godoc.org/strconv#Itoa)

```
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+strconv.Itoa(conf.PORT), router))
```

or [fmt.Sprintf](https://godoc.org/fmt#Sprintf) to convert the integer to a decimal representation

```
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d",conf.PORT), router))
```

A more flexible and simpler approach is specify the complete address as a string in the configuration. This allows the IP address to be specified in the configuration.

Answer (score 5):

[Global variable initializers and package `init()` functions will always run before `main()`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_initialization_and_execution). If your `getGeneralConfig` function launches a goroutine, but you need it to complete before `main()` runs, either a) don't use a goroutine, or b) use a [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) to ensure it completes before `getGeneralConfig` returns.

Comment: This answer does not suggest the use of `init()`. It does answer OP's specific question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when converting int to string. Just use `strconv` package to convert `int` value to `string` as:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

var conf = getGeneralConfig()

func getGeneralConfig() int {
    return 8080
}

func main() {
    //router := mux.NewRouter()
    fmt.Println(":" + strconv.Itoa(conf))
   // router.HandleFunc("/add", add).Methods("POST")
   // conf is not yet ready here
   // log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+string(conf.PORT), router))
}
```

Check [playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/zeFNUZHyO2U)